# Как объединить части круговой диаграммы (matplotlib.pie)

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть набор данных (70 значений) типа Float надо создать круговую диаграмму где значения большие 2,6 будут отображены отдельными частями(долями) а те значения которые  меньше 2,6 надо объединить в одну большую часть одного цвета и без деления.
Ссылка на DF https://github.com/Raduga-maker/Pandas

Comment: если честно, вопрос вообще не понятен что надо сделать, так же приложите код со своими попытками реализации. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Постарался исправить чтобы стало понятнее, заранее простите второй раз задаю здесь вопрос

Comment: Может стоит обработать датафрейм определённым образом?

Comment: вы данные (таблицу) в текстовом виде приведите. зачем нам их фотография?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как выводить данные, вы можете прогнать их через пороговую лямбду, так как вашего исходного датафрейма я не вижу, поэтому я реализую собственный образовательный пример.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Ваш исходный список x
x = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 200, 500]

# Создаем DataFrame из списка x
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': x})

# Объединяем значения меньше 100 в один кусок пирога
threshold = 100
data['values'] = data['values'].apply(lambda val: val if val >= threshold else f'меньше чем {threshold}')

# Группируем данные по значениям и суммируем их
grouped_data = data.groupby('values').size()

# Создаем круговую диаграмму на основе сгруппированных данных
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=72)
plt.pie(grouped_data, labels=grouped_data.index, autopct='%1.1f%%')

# Отображаем диаграмму (опционально)
plt.show()
```

Мои `values` в вашем случае будут отражать ваши проценты, а где `threshold` укажите ваше пороговое значение

Выглядеть будет это следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]